# Programmatically generated button not performing action

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am trying to add some buttons dynamically in UITableViewCell.I have created method "tappedButton" which is supposed to call when any of those buttons get clicked but its not working properly. I need to press 3 or 4 times and then hardly the action happens.Can anyone suggest me a better way to do this.

```
    func tappedButton(sender: UIButton!) {
            print("tapped button---->"+(sender.titleLabel?.text)!)
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("web", sender: self)
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MagazineTableViewCell
                 // headings is global variable , an array of string
                 for td in headings {
                    let button:UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, t, 500, 26))
                    t+=36
                    button.setTitle(td,forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                    let black=hexStringToUIColor("#000000")
                    let white=hexStringToUIColor("#ffffff")
                    button.backgroundColor = black
                    button.setTitleColor(white, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MainTableViewController.tappedButton(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.AllTouchEvents)
                    // searchView is a black UIView in which I dynamically add buttons
                    cell.searchView.addSubview(button)
                  }

         return cell
    }
```

Comment: have you tried `tappedButton(_:)` instead of `MainTableViewController.tappedButton(_:)`?

Answer (score 0):

You should add your Button in your cell's subclass. Then addTarget in your cellforRowAtIndexParh. Please try it and let me know. + change in your addTarget with `.touchDown` Instead of `.AllTouchEvents`

Answer (score 0):

You'd better add `UIButton` into your prototype cell and then just add

```
yourButton.hidden = true
```

if you want it to be hidden. Note that you should add

```
yourButton.hidden = false
```

after

```
let cell = ..
```

to make it work fine when cells are reused.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to update the cellForRowAtIndexPath method like below.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MagazineTableViewCell

        //remove existing buttons
        for subView in cell.searchView.subviews{

            subView.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        // headings is global variable , an array of string
        for td in headings {
            let button:UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, t, 500, 26))
            t+=36
            button.setTitle(td,forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            let black=hexStringToUIColor("#000000")
            let white=hexStringToUIColor("#ffffff")
            button.backgroundColor = black
            button.setTitleColor(white, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MainTableViewController.tappedButton(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
            // searchView is a black UIView in which I dynamically add buttons
            cell.searchView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            cell.searchView.addSubview(button)
        }

        return cell
    }
```

You are trying to add the button to cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method in which the buttons will be overlapped whenever `cellForRowAtIndexPath` called. So first yo should remove the existing buttons from `searchView` and add your dynamic(headings) buttons in for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I have replicated your scenario in a basic project:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

  let numberOfButtons = 3
  var currentButtonYPosition: CGFloat = 0

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    currentButtonYPosition = 0

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    for index in 0..<numberOfButtons {
      let button = UIButton()
      button.frame = CGRectMake(0, currentButtonYPosition, tableView.frame.width, 30)
      button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
      button.setTitle(String(index), forState: .Normal)
      button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonWasTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

      cell.innerView.addSubview(button)

      currentButtonYPosition += 40
    }

    return cell
  }

  func buttonWasTapped(button: UIButton) {
    print("button \(button.currentTitle!) was tapped")
  }
}
```

Result

[image]